# Best way to handle multiple lists in redis?

Tags: redis

I am building a site that allows users to view and do some activities (vote, comments,...) on articles. I am using MySql  as main storage. In order to improve performance, I am considering using `Redis (4.x)` to handle some view activities such as top/hot articles...

I am gonna use one sortedSet, called `topAticleSortedSet`, to store top articles, and this set will be updated frequently every time a user vote or somment on a certain article.

Since each user will login and follow some topics and I also need to filter and display articles in the `topArticleSortedSet` based on users' following topics.

There is of course scroll paging as well.

For those reasons, I intend to create one topArticleSortedSet for each user and that way each user will have one independent list. But I dont know if this is best practice because there might be million of logged-in users access in my site (then it would be million of sets which is around 1000 article items for each).

Can anyone give me some advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep to one Set, and filter it for each user, instead of having a Set per user. Here is why:

My understanding is that the Set have to be updated each time someone reads an article (incrementing a counter probably).

Let's say you have n users, each one reading p articles per day. So you have to update the Set n*p times a day.

In the "single" set option, you will need to update just one set when there is an article read. So it makes a total of n*p updates. In the "one set per user" architecture, you will need to do n*p*n updates, which is much bigger.

Of course, filtering a single Set will take you some time, longer than accessing a Set designed for one user. But on average, I guess it would take you much less time than n operations. **Basically, you need to know which is faster: filtering one Set or updating n Sets ?**

Comment: But if using one Set, I am afraid that user would experience inconsistent data when performing paging since the order of the Set will be updated frequently. What do you think of that?

Comment: check transactions : http://redis.io/topics/transactions  . In particulare, "It can never happen that a request issued by another client is served in the middle of the execution of a Redis transaction."